# 3d model to point cloud

Tags: software-recommendations, 3d, point-cloud

Excepting [FME](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Creating-Point-Clouds-from-3D-models-or-rasters), is there a way to convert 3d model to point cloud?

Comment: You may check PCL: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/walkthrough.php